# Recommendations for presentation software with realtime scrolling text

Tags: reporting, presentation

What's the best software / tool stack to display realtime scrolling names and a chart that shows a graph of donations?  This is for a fundraising event and would be shown on the big screen.  Donations will be received real-time and will be entered into a database. We want to have a live presentation that scrolls through the donors names as they are entered in the DB and have a graph that updates to show the total donations.  Ideally we would like to be able to run this through a laptop and not be dependent on a cloud service as internet connectivity may not be solid at the event site.

Comment: Have you thought about the privacy implications of this?

Comment: Yes - on the privacy question.  The display name the donor specifies is what would be shown and it could display Anonymous, in memory of, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do it yourself, and don't mind paying for the license, DevExpress seems to have the ability to do real time charts, if you don't want to pay for a license, then there is plenty of libraries that can do realtime charting in any imaginable plataform.